# Xamarin entry behaviour and INotifyPropertyChanged crashes

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, behavior

First of all, my app is multilingual and it makes some mathematical calculations in a listview.

This listview is bound to a Observable Collection with a model. In model inside the setter area I have INotifyPropertyChanged to update the UI.

On the other hand, I have a behaviour class, which converts comma to dot. 
When the phone's language is English, there is no problem, but when I change the language to German, as you know, the culture settings sets a comma as default separator and the problem starts. The entry behaviour and the INotifyPropertyChanged are conflicting and the app crashes.

How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
public class NumericValidationBehavior : Behavior<Entry>
    {

        protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged += OnEntryTextChanged;

            base.OnAttachedTo(entry);
        }

        protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry entry)
        {
            entry.TextChanged -= OnEntryTextChanged;

            base.OnDetachingFrom(entry);

        }

        private static void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args)
        {


            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(args.NewTextValue))
            {

                bool isValid = args.NewTextValue.ToCharArray().All(x => char.IsDigit(x));

                if (!isValid)
                {
                    ((Entry)sender).Text = args.NewTextValue.Replace(",", ".");
                    //if i remove this line, the app doesnt crash...
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ((Entry)sender).Text = "0";
            }
        }
    }

private double stockTotal;
public double StockTotal 
{ 
  get
  {
    return stockTotal;
  }
  set 
  {
     stockTotal = value;
     PropertyChanged("StockTotal");
    //if i remove this line, the app doesnt crash...

  }
}
```

the video shows more details. 
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGmmPtyaML8)

[I upload the video...you can watch the problem](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGmmPtyaML8)

Comment: "app crashes" - this is not a helpful description of the problem.  What is the exception causing the crash?  Which line of code causes the crash?

Comment: if i delete this 
((Entry)sender).Text = args.NewTextValue.Replace(",", "."); 

or

 PropertyChanged("StockTotal");

the app does not crash...

Comment: that line causes OnEntryTextChanged to get called recursively

Comment: Yes, i tried to write 1.2 inside the entry... 
 2 times, in the setter area the value is 1.2 and 2 times 12.  Freezes in this cycle...Repeats again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downgraded the XamarinForms version from 4.5 to 4.3.0.991221.

Then, I deleted the NumericValidationBehavior Class.
Now it's working.